# Sabre webservices SOAP: using PO_PNRPricingRQ

Tags: sabre

Normally, I would have to book an itinerary using Y class using OTA_AirBookRQ, and then issue a WPNCB#PJCB to get the lowest JCB fare that is available, then I issue a WPDF to get a breakdown of the cost of a given routing per fare basis code and taxes.
I'm trying to find out if there is a faster way of getting to the breakdown. Documentation for PO_PNRPricingRQ seems to indicate that it's possible, but the solution eludes me.
How can I use PO_PNRPricingRQ to price lowest JCB fare that is available? If it's possible, can you provide an example request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use OTA_AirLowFareSearchLLSRQ? Thats a shopping service, checks availability and price at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. I will check on that option. As I understand, each of these requests have different costs associated with them, so that may be the reason why this request was skipped.